# Save the text of each element of a List<TextBox> into a new List<string>

Tags: c#, winforms, list, text, textbox

I have a list that contains textboxes:

```
List<TextBox> myListTB = new List<TextBox>();
```

Each item in the list is a textbox and I would like to have a new list of strings containing only the field Text of each textbox. 
How can I do this? 
I tried:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList = myListTB.ForEach(Text);
```

and then I wanted to convert string to doubles but this doesn't work. 
Can you please help?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Get the text from the textboxes stored in the List collection? Post code please

Answer (score 2):

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < myListTB.Count(); i++)
        {
            myList.Add(myListTB[i].Text);
        }
```

or

```
        foreach(TextBox x in myListTB)
        {
            myList.Add(x.Text);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This can all be done with Linq

```
var doubles = myListTb.Select(t => Double.Parse(t.Text)).ToList();
```